# vb.net Tracking user tasks dynamically

Tags: vb.net, filter

I'm trying to build an application which tracks and manages tasks. Currently this is controlled on an excel spreadsheet [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hAox.png) using some VBA. Tasks are updated regularly throughout the day, some are closed off etc.

I've looked at  implementing a these tasks in a listview control but this has the disadvantage of not being able to hide rows as part of a filter routine.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTRrX.png) is a mock of up of what I would like to achieve. I'm not able to use n access database and I am considering using XML files to store the data as this is in my experience much smoother.

Does anyone know of a better way of achieving what I am after?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Firstly, I hate to make mention of the obvious, but SO is for programming related issues, rather than opinions. Also we need to see where your code is failing - there being no code, there is no opportunity to help. However, that being said, *imo*, install SQL Express and have a play around with using that. All the code you could possibly want for examples is provided on how to cleanly insert, update and delete data - how to bind it to controls - and how to filter it using either LINQ or other code sets. It easily integrates with Visual Studio as well.

Comment: I don't know how to embed links, but please visit this: How do I ask a good question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your response - I understand this question isn't strictly code related but i find SO a valuable forum for people like myself who have never had formal training in programming but understand processes. I'll take a look into SQL express - i know our company has the full version so this could be a good way to go.

Comment: @DeeKayy90 : Links can be embedded like this: `[Link description](Link)`, for instance: `[Google](http://www.google.com/)`. For more see: [Markdown Editing help - Links](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links).

Comment: No worries, I guess my concern is that I don't want to see a question where someone is genuinely looking for hints closed where it could help others. In the case of SQL, have a play around and create a test database, have a look at normalising your data (extract customer, engineer, etc.) - you have a good basis to create the task/user/customer tables in the excel document, and these can be used to autopopulate drop downs for your task system. (FYI, your `taskmanager` tag is for the Windows task manager, not a task management system :) ) Good luck mate!